# How to resize an object to fit inside the hole just made with boolean difference

Tags: modifiers, objects, 3d-printing, object-mode, boolean-modifier

How can I resize my Empire logo to fit inside the hole just made with Boolean (Difference)on the box?

I have made a few attempts with the measuring tool and shrinking it down, but it seems to not really work that well. parts of it seem to never fit.

This is for a 3d print, I made an SD card holder and I would like to set the Empire symbol inside as an inlay that extends out just a bit

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: This might help....
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275418/how-do-i-use-the-geometry-of-one-object-to-make-a-corresponding-socket-in-anothe/276224#276224

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method would be to use the same geo that you used to do the Boolean. Then change your world space to local, set your pivot space to individual. Go into edit mode and use your use face selection to get all of your  faces on your outer edge and scale down/up. You will have todo this for each of your edges rings one at a time. [image] I hope that was helpful!