# Garage Kit/3D Printing

Tags: 3d-printing

I'm a total beginner at blender, and I want to eventually make garage kits and 3D print them one day. I've been searching on how to make the separate parts and create exact holes in the shape of squares and a "peg" or connector of some sort that will connect the two pieces exactly. But I haven't found anything, how do I do that? Sorry if I didn't use any of the correct terms, I'm not sure what they are actually called.

Comment: This sounds like the job for a CAD application like FreeCAD rather than an animation software like Blender

Comment: Google Maker Tales and CAD Sketcher Addon for Blender

Comment: See if this helps.  I do this all the time.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275418/how-do-i-use-the-geometry-of-one-object-to-make-a-corresponding-socket-in-anothe/276224#276224